# How to select second max value for each rows (MySQL)

Tags: mysql

Table looks like below.

```
+-------+------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id    | int  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| count | int  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

id value can be duplicated.
I want to select second max value for each id.

For example,

```
+------+-------+
| id   | count |
+------+-------+
|    1 |    10 |
|    1 |     6 |
|    1 |     3 |
|    5 |    11 |
|    5 |    15 |
|    2 |     4 |
|    2 |     8 |
+------+-------+
```

In this case, I want to select like below.

```
+------+-------+
| id   | count |
+------+-------+
|    1 |     6 |
|    5 |    11 |
|    2 |     4 |
+------+-------+
```

How can i select it?

Comment: What's is the logic of your expect result?

Comment: @D-Shih He said in the question: The second highest count grouped by id.

Comment: You can find several similar questions with this search: `[mysql] nth highest in group`